# How to pass a dynamic string in Javascript function which contains (',")

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, rss

I am working with RSS Feeds.  I would like to pass the link and title to a Javascript function like this.

```
'<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="shareFb(\''+item.link+'\',\''+item.title+'\')"></a>'
```

This item.link and item.title are dynamically generated.  If the link contains some words like (facebook's) etc.. that (') single quotes and some other characters make a problem and browser console was throwing an error `uncaught syntaxerror: unexpected identifier.` If the title and link I am passing contains plain text then I am able to pass those as arguments.  Is there any idea to make it work.

Comment: use encodeURIComponent();

Comment: why not just $('a').click(function(){ shareFb(item.link, item.title); });

Comment: '<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="shareFb('+item.link+','+item.title+')"></a>'  Use this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
'<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="shareFb(\''+encodeURIComponent(item.link)+'\',\''+encodeURIComponent(item.title)+'\')"></a>'
```

Answer (score 0):

In the item title, replace the occurences of `'` with `\'`

Change

```
item.title
```

to

```
item.title.replace('\'', '\\'')
```

Answer (score 0):

Like you said, there are problematic characters. On the server side, try escaping the item.link and item.title.

In C#, you would use: HttpUtility.UrlEncode, for example. In JavaScript, you would use encodeURI(). Then when you want to decode the parameter, use decodeURI().

Answer (score 0):

In item.link you can use encodeURIComponent

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_encodeuricomponent